# How to re-run iteration from ADF pipeline?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an ADF pipeline parent that it's calling another pipeline child, and this child has a DataFlow that it's running a Kusto (ADX) query from the source and exporting into ADLSv2.

I am doing that 4 times, because I am partitioning the data. Something is happening with the source that it's not retrieving any data for a given partition, but if I copy that same query and run against the source the data will be there just fine. But ADF also is not complaining about that for some reason, so retry is not working in this case.

This dataset that we are exporting is huge, that's why we are partitioning in 4 times like that, that's the only way we found to make it run.

Parent pipeline:

[image]

Child pipeline:

[image]

DataFlow:

[image]

Note: In the dataflow, a short explanation:

Write order 1. It's querying results to use in the Source (Write order 3)
Write order 2. Dummy source, so I can see the query even if runs fails
Write order 3. Real data, that's where I cam retrieving data that I need to export

I know that it's not retrieving data for a given partition on the run, because I am ingesting metadata from ADF to Kusto to understand what is happening, and for some runs that is happening.

I can also see from the Pipeline output:

Results with rows:

```
"metrics": {
            "dsADLSv2Parquet": {
                "format": "parquet",
                "stages": [
                    {
                        "stage": 167,
                        "partitionTimes": [],
                        "recordsWritten": 0,
                        "lastUpdateTime": "2024-02-08 08:58:50.290",
                        "bytesWritten": 0,
                        "recordsRead": 0,
                        "bytesRead": 0,
                        "partitionStatus": "Success",
                        "streams": {},
                        "target": "dsADLSv2Parquet",
                        "time": 386,
                        "progressState": "Completed"
                    },
                    {
                        "stage": 168,
                        "partitionTimes": [],
                        "recordsWritten": 32739769,
                        "lastUpdateTime": "2024-02-08 08:59:13.872",
                        "bytesWritten": 326937658,
                        "recordsRead": 32739769,
                        "bytesRead": 1166855315,
                        "partitionStatus": "Success",
                        "streams": {
                            "dsADLSv2Parquet": {
                                "count": 32739769,
                                "cached": false,
                                "totalPartitions": 0,
                                "partitionStatus": "Success",
                                "partitionCounts": [],
                                "type": "sink"
                            }
                        },
                        "target": "dsADLSv2Parquet",
                        "time": 23061,
                        "progressState": "Completed"
                    }
                ],
                "sinkPostProcessingTime": 0,
                "store": "adlsgen2",
                "rowsWritten": 32739769,
                "details": {
                    "postCommandsDuration": [
                        0
                    ],
                    "preCommandsDuration": [
                        0
                    ]
                },
                "progressState": "Completed",
                "sources": {},
                "sinkProcessingTime": 146321
            }
}
```

Results with no rows:

```
"metrics": {}
```

What can be done?

Comment: Without details on the source filtering to Azure Data Explorer difficult to answer. What was the reason not to use continuous export in Azure Data Explorer? That would avoid data movement (to the cluster used by Data Flow).

Comment: @HaukeMallow because we are doing some transformations in data flow in some iterations, so we needed to do on ADF. I am afraid the Kusto might be showing some error maybe, but I don't know if ADF has any kind of configuration that is bypassing that and continuing the iteration without concerns.